# Math.Round returning a rounded up for odd values but rounds down for even

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I am trying to found a float using math round
I found the following

```
0.5 --> 0
1.5 --> 2
2.5 --> 2
3.5 --> 4
```

and so on.
I believe this is due to floating point error, but not quite sure how. 
How can I get around this so even numbers round properly?

Comment: What do you expect? What do you mean by “even numbers round properly”? (actually they are “rounding properly” in your example for “properly” defined as “midpoints go to the nearest even number”).

Comment: thanks heaps for the fast responses! I feel a bit silly now, never heard of this before. Not how I was taught in school :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> The integer nearest a. **If the fractional component of a is halfway
>   between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the
>   even number is returned.** Note that this method returns a Double
>   instead of an integral type.

`Math.Round` method has some [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Round.aspx) that takes [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a parameter which you can specify the rounding value if it is midway between two numbers.

```
AwayFromZero
```

> When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the
>   nearest number that is away from zero.

```
ToEven
```

> When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the
>   nearest even number.

Comment: I wonder what happens when it's halfway between two integers, both of which are even... Redundancy FTW!

Comment: and why say "the fractional component of a", rather than just "a"?  As it is, the statement seems incorrect:  e.g., if `a = 3.5`, the fractional component of `a` is `0.5`, and a strict reading of that sentence might lead you to believe that `0.0` is returned.  (Complaining about the MSDN content; not this answer.)

Answer (score 6):

You could use this one, to overcome that you have stated:

```
Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Using the above:

> When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the
>   nearest number that is away from zero.

For further documentation about the `MidpointRounding` enumeration, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks heaps, I though that it was floating point after a bit of research. Didn't even think to check documentation! Sorry!!

Comment: Now to continue with test :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this

```
 Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the fractional component of a is halfway between two integers, one
>   of which is even and the other odd, then the even number is returned.

Also to mention one important point which I think is good to mention is that Microsoft has followed the **[IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Roundings_to_nearest)**. This is also mentioned in MSDN for Math.Round under Remarks which says:

> **Round to nearest, ties to even** – rounds to the nearest value; if the number falls midway it is rounded to the nearest value with an
>   even (zero) least significant bit, which occurs 50% of the time; this
>   is the default for binary floating-point and the recommended default
>   for decimal.
>
> **Round to nearest, ties away from zero** – rounds to the nearest value; if the number falls midway it is rounded to the nearest value
>   above (for positive numbers) or below (for negative numbers); this is
>   intended as an option for decimal floating point.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as bankers rounding (round to even). You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx). This is a .NET Framework feature and is working as designed.

Comment: Well, it's a framework feature. It's not part of the C# *language*.

Comment: Thanks Jon - Corrected my answer